# Is the first scene in Miller's Crossing a parody or homage of the first scene in The Godfather?

Tags: the-godfather, millers-crossing

In the first scene of the movie The Godfather we see a supplicant ask Vito Corleone (the capo del capo) for a favour.

In the first scene of [Miller's Crossing](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100150/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) we see something similar where a junior crime boss requests a favour from the top crime boss. Obviously there are big differences: the era is earlier and the outcome is the kicking off point for the complex events of the movie whereas the scene in The Godfather is more for introducing the nature of the characters and doesn't incite the plot.

But the scene is set in a room very like the scene in The Godfather, it is lit in a similar way, with similar players taking part on a smaller scale.

Is the scene in Miller's Crossing an intentional homage or even a parody of the scene in The Godfather?

Comment: Miller's Crossing wikipedia page list Orr in The Atlantic writing that the opening is a nod to Godfather. Side note: parody is also a homage.

Comment: The words are not synonymous. 'Homage' infers sincerity, where 'parody' infers a level of derision.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I disagree. Young Frankenstein is undeniably a parody of the first three Universal Frankenstein movies but there is no derision involved. It was done with great respect and affection for the genre.

Comment: Mary Shelley herself would have been proud to watch it, I'm sure.  The key plot elements particular to the monster and its origin were mocking, however.  You can't have it both ways.  Some level of joking has to happen with a parody.  An homage is purely respect.